# C++ Makefile that includes ddd debugger option

Tags: c++, debugging, makefile

I'm kind of new to Makefiles and i'm trying to include a debugger option in my makefile that opens the debugger when I type "make debug." However, that command returns an error. I already have the ddd debugger installed in my virtual machine. This is my makefile below. Any help?

```
main: main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp
    g++ --std=c++11 -o main main.cpp
    ./main
clean:
    -rm -f *.o main
debug:
    g++ --std=c++11 -g debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp ddd debug
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
g++ --std=c++11 -g debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp ddd debug
```

This line is in error. It tells G++ to compile, using the options `--std=c++11 -g`, the list of files given -- including "ddd" and "debug" (twice) -- to `a.out` (or `a.exe` if you're on Windows / Cygwin).

That is not what you wanted, and as "debug" and "ddd" are unlikely to be valid C++ source files, the compiler run fails.

---

If you type `make debug`, then `make` will execute the `debug` rule:

```
debug:
    g++ --std=c++11 -g debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp ddd debug
```

If no file named `debug` exists (*), `make` will attempt to recreate it using the command:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -g debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp ddd debug
```

I don't quite know what you *expect* that command to do. I *guess* that you intended two commands to be executed in sequence:

```
debug:
    g++ --std=c++11 -g debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp
    ddd debug
```

However, the compiler line is in error. I *guess* you wanted something like this (note the `-o`):

```
g++ --std=c++11 -g -o debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp
```

---

```
main: main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp
    g++ --std=c++11 -o main main.cpp
    ./main
```

This is broken several ways.

This rule instructs `make` to rebuild `main` from scratch whenever *any* of the files `main.cpp`, `puzzle.cpp` or `fuse.cpp` is touched. However, the *command* you are giving only recompiles `main.cpp` -- the other two files are never (re)compiled.

A *good* Makefile rule only does what is needed to (re)build the file it is named by, and is as generic as possible.

For example, to "tell" make how to create a `*.o` file from any given `*.cpp` file (`$@` and `@<` being placeholder for "target of rule" and "first dependency", respectively):

```
%.o: %.cpp
    g++ --std=c++11 -o $@ @<
```

Once you have that, you can tell make how to build your executable from individual object files (`$^` being a placeholder for "*all* the dependencies"):

```
main: main.o puzzle.o fuse.o
    g++ --std=c++11 -o $@ $^
```

This way, if you touch one of the source files (e.g. `puzzle.cpp`), only that *one* object file gets rebuilt, and the `main` executable relinked. With large projects, this *significantly* reduces (re)compile times.

---

(*) If you have rules that do *not* actually create a file, you should label them as `.PHONY`, so `make` will execute them *even if a file by that name happens to exist already*.

You also usually want to disable optimization for debugging, to avoid some of the stranger things that can happen with optimization on.

So (for easier example compiling *with* `-g` debugging information always):

```
.PHONY: debug

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ --std=c++11 -g -O0 -o $@ @<

main: main.o puzzle.o fuse.o
    g++ --std=c++11 -g -O0 -o $@ @^

debug: main
    ddd main
```

---

What your Makefile *also* does not take into account is that an object file *also* needs to be recompiled when any of the *header files* it includes are touched. This kind of dependency handling is easy to do with GCC, but beyond the scope of this answer. Let me point to the [Makefile tutorial at OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile) (which was mostly written by me) for a step-by-step introduction on how to get a Makefile "right".

Answer (score 2):

`ddd debug` needs to be on a line by itself to execute as a separate command, and you need to add the missing `-o` switch:

```
debug:
    g++ --std=c++11 -g -o debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp
    ddd debug
```

However, this will not execute if `debug` already exists; `make` tries to optimize and it will not run a recipe if the target already exists, or is newer than the listed dependencies (which are none).

Instead, break this rule up into two pieces.  The binary (with dependencies listed), and the run command (which should be marked as a phony target).  The phony target will make sure that the recipe still runs even if there is a file with the same name as the recipe's output name (`run-debug` in this example).

```
debug: main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp
    g++ --std=c++11 -g -o debug main.cpp puzzle.cpp fuse.cpp

run-debug: debug
    ddd debug

.PHONY: run-debug
```

This way, `make run-debug` will always invoke the debugger (if compilation succeeded), but compilation will not be performed if the `debug` binary is newer than your source files.

---

I'm not super-familiar with `ddd`, but some debuggers will look up the binary in a similar way to shells, so you may need to modify the `ddd` line to be:

```
ddd ./debug
```

---

Don't forget to patch up your `clean` rule to (1) delete `debug` and (2) be phony:

```
clean:
    -rm -f *.o main debug

.PHONY: clean run-debug
```